# Image size on Read the Docs (small images width)

Tags: css, read-the-docs, mkdocs

I'm using [MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) to generate docs using Markdown, and the theme Read the Docs.

However, I'm having trouble getting small images from scaling up on mobile phones.

I think this is linked to the Read the Docs CSS, but I'm having trouble understanding what should I do to override the behavior of setting `width:100%` on small screens.

The CSS applied to a certain image on a big screen (using chrome inspection) is:

```
.rst-content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

But if I reduce the screen, I get this extra CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

I'm able to manually set the image size, for example:

```
<img src="/something.png" style="width: 25px">
```

But I would prefer if I could create some CSS to ensure that this is applied to all images, so I don't have to add this HTML tag on the middle of the Markdown file each time I want to add a small image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify the media query (or create a new rule with higher [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)) to set the `width` of the images to `auto` for narrow viewports:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I cannot find this attribute in [Read the Docs CSS](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/master/mkdocs/themes/readthedocs/css/theme.css) I don't know the specificity. 
Unfortunately, the CSS you provide doesn't change anything.